# Calculate the number of months between two dates in decimal form. (Ex: Feb 15th to April 3rd = ~2.59 months) In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm, datetime, math

I need this to be as accurate as possible based on real dates, leap years, Feb's 28 or 29 days etc... if possible. I can't seem to find any question similar to this one. Thank you so much for your help and time.

Comment: Why is that 2.59 months? How many days does this "month" unit have? Expressing anything in terms of fractional months is always an approximation, there is no such thing as "accurate".

Comment: The problem with having decimal months is that once you use finer units than "day", your decimal value depends on the local government's definition of daylight savings, among other things.

Comment: 15 Apr to 15 Mar is 1 month, 16 Mar to 3 Apr is 18 days, which is 0.58 of Mar or 0.6 of Apr so the difference should be 1.58 or 1.6. You need to explain the rules and attempt some code.

Answer (score 1):

Date calculations sure can be a hassle. May I suggest using a library, such as [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/)?

Maybe this is the function you are looking for
[the differenceInMonths function in date-fns](https://date-fns.org/v2.11.1/docs/differenceInMonths), but that returns an integer number of months.

If you definitely want to have a decimal number, you could assume the [average length of a month to be 30.436875](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Month). Given that, you could use [the differenceInDays function in date-fns](https://date-fns.org/v2.11.1/docs/differenceInDays) to get the difference in days, and divide that by the average number of days in a month.